# Regresión logística en R

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un análisis de regresión logística binaria (rlb) con glm(). Quiero hacer un modelo multiplicativo, pero no obtengo el valor que preciso. Y no sé muy bien cómo conseguirlo. Voy a poner unas comparativas con SPSS para intentar explicarlo:

Mediante R hago lo siguiente (es un código general):

```
fit1 <- glm(unlist(df1$var_dep) ~ unlist(df1$var_1) * unList(df1$var_2), data = df1, family = binomial)
fit1 <- fit1 %>% tidy(conf.int =TRUE, exp = TRUE)
```

Con esto obtengo lo siguiente:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  term                                                estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
  <chr>                                                  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept)                                            0.300    0.0432     -27.9 3.99e-171   0.275      0.326
2 unlist(df1$var_1)                                      7.62     0.0905      22.4 1.79e-111   6.39       9.12 
3 unlist(df1$var_2)                                      5.71     0.125       13.9 3.88e- 44   4.48       7.32 
4 unlist(df1$var_1):unlist(df1$var_2)                    0.110    0.205      -10.8 4.12e- 27   0.0736     0.164
```

Ese resultado es equivalente en SPSS cuando añado en el apartado de "Bloque 1 de 1 en "Analizar/Regresión/logística binaria": var1, var2 y var_1*var_2. Muestro la salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo lo que quiero es el resultado equivalente a meter en SPSS solo var_1*var_2:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de mucho probar, la solución era simple. Os dejo el código, por si a alguien le es útil:

```
fit1 <- glm(unlist(df1$var_dep) ~ unlist(df1$var_1):unlist(df1$var_2), data = taxones1, family = binomial)
fit1 <- fit1 %>% tidy(conf.int =TRUE, exp = TRUE)


# A tibble: 2 × 7
  term                                       estimate std.error statistic  p.value conf.low conf.high
  <chr>                                        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept)                                  0.530    0.0329    -19.3  6.12e-83    0.497     0.565
2 unlist(df1$var_1):unlist(df1$var_2)          2.71     0.145       6.87 6.54e-12    2.04      3.61
```

Comment: no es necesario usar `unlist`, tu modelo podría quedar de la siguiente manera: `glm(var_dep ~ var_1:var_2, data = df1, family = binomial)`. Nota que no hay correspondencia entre el input que diste en `data` y el uso de `df1$.`